# My network icon is always a question mark and I can't access internet on any network

Tags: networking, internet

`lspci -knn grep - i net -A3`

```
O2:OO.O Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Ca., Ltd. RTL8111/8168
/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit
 Ethernet Controller [103c:8331]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
03:OO.O Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Screen

[image]

Screen2

[image]

I'm typing this from my desktop PC Windows OS. My laptop runs Ubuntu and until just recently I've tried to connect to my school network, but gave up since nothing worked.

```
RFKILL list
0: Phy8: Wireless LAN
         Soft Blocked:no
         Hard blocked:no
1: hci0:Bluetooth
Soft Blocked: no
RFKILL list

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
hard blocked: no
1:hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked :no
```

I've never been able to use any networks. I can connect to them but I can't do anything. And my internet icon in the top right is just a question mark.

What can I try?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68393/discussion-on-question-by-acediaxe-belz-my-internet-icon-is-always-a-question-ma).

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the content of [your chat session](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68393/discussion-on-question-by-acediaxe-belz-my-internet-icon-is-always-a-question-ma) you should revert the `/etc/network interfaces` file that you edited to it's default content:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

According to the info in your question, there's no issue with the kernel drivers in use and both the wired and wireless connections are properly recognized. Your wireless interface is not blocked so this should resolve your issue. If not, drop me a comment and I'll expand my answer as necessary.